# How to distinguish between items returned by EnumObjects of IShellFolder

Tags: c++, shell

I am trying to get the computers in my workgroup using Shell

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
ULONG celtFetched;
LPITEMIDLIST pidlItems = NULL;
LPITEMIDLIST netItemIdLst = NULL;
IShellFolder* pFolder = NULL;
IEnumIDList* pEnumIds = NULL;
IShellFolder* pDesktopFolder = NULL;
LPITEMIDLIST full_pid;

hr = SHGetMalloc(&pMalloc);
hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktopFolder);
hr = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, CSIDL_COMPUTERSNEARME, &netItemIdLst);
hr = pDesktopFolder->BindToObject(netItemIdLst, NULL, 
                                  IID_IShellFolder, (void **)&pFolder);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &pEnumIds);

  if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
    STRRET strDisplayName;
    while((hr = pEnumIds->Next(1, &pidlItems, &celtFetched)) == S_OK && celtFetched > 0)
    {
      hr = pFolder->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlItems, SHGDN_NORMAL, &strDisplayName);
      if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", strDisplayName.pOleStr);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this returns the Computers, Media Devices, and Streaming Devices (is that it name?).
Like say, a computer is called `OSOFEM` on my workgroup... `STRRET::pOleStr` returns strings `OSOFEM` (which is the computer), `OSOFEM` (I think streaming device), and `OSOFEM:example@email.com:` (which is the Windows Media Player).

My question is how can I distinguish which is the Computer? Of course, there names can't be used because two exactly the same name will always be returned...